# Reinstalling a package on Solaris 11

Tags: installation, solaris, package-management, gcc, reinstall

I installed gcc 4 on Solaris 11 using

```
pkg-get gcc4g++
```

near the end of the installation process it showed a warning that some script didn't run succesfully (which I didn't write down unfortunately). Now some include files are missing (eg. math_iso.h).

I would like to try to re-install the package, but I haven't found a command to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Solaris 11 to try it out, but "pkgrm" is the Solaris 10 way to do it.

Comment: pkgrm doesn't find the gcc4g++ package. It seems only to work on packages installed with pkg, not with pkg-get.

Comment: pkgrm is for packages installed with pkgadd, the old SVR4 package system used on Solaris 10 and earlier.   pkg-get is a wrapper around the SVR4 package system used by the Blastwave & OpenCSW projects.   pkg is part of the new Solaris 11 packaging system.

Comment: pkgrm worked, but the package that pkg-get called gcc4g++ was called CSWgcc4g++ for pkgrm. Thanks!

Comment: If you were using pkg-get, you were probably using OpenCSW.  Each package is using two names: a pkgname and a catalogname.  The pkgname is what Solaris uses to identify packages.  Catalogname is what pkg-get uses to identify packages when downloading them from the catalog.